# How to select all elements with particular ARIA value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, wai-aria

Given i have a sample page that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 aria-controls="name1">heading</h1>

<p aria-controls="name2">paragraph</p>

<span aria-controls="name1">span</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How would i use jQuery to select the (2) elements with their `aria-controls` attribute set to `name1`? (ignoring the fact that the element types are different).

Thank you!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The attribute selector

```
[aria-controls="name1"]
```

should work.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: thank you sir.  works great. I can't accept the answer yet... but in 10 minutes i will.

Answer (score 22):

Use something like this -

**[WORKING DEMO](http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/FoJlj)**

```
var elements = $("body").find("[aria-controls='name1']");
```

Above is for if you want to look for elements within a container eg body in this case, it can be some div also.

--OR--

```
var elements = $("[aria-controls='name1']");
```

Above is for if you want to get all the elements with this attribute